# ifup eth0 - /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables exec format error

Tags: linux, networking, debian, iptables, linux-networking

I am currently unable to bring `eth0` up again at my Debian 10 vServer after my hosting provider was fixing some issues and restarted my container.

`sudo service networking status` will output:

```
ifup[378]: run-parts: failed to exec /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables: Exec format error
ifup[378]: run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables exited with return code 1
ifup[378]: ifup: pre-up script failed
```

which is the same output provided by `ifup eth0`, supplemented by

```
ifup: failed to bring up eth0
```

In `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables`, there is:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

The `iptables`-file is stored with the following permissions: `-rwxr-xr-x`

Running `/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules` manually does not provide any output and commenting that line out doesn't do the trick, either. However, the routes have been loaded.

`/etc/iptables.up.rules` has `-rw-r--r--` and has the following content:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -s 45.142.120.0/24 -j DROP 
COMMIT
```

Any ideas how to further deal with this?